# fliped foreign key relations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i have a strange effekt at a m:n relation..
this are the model definitions:

Role Model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
    uuid: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    ....
  }, {});
  /** @param models.User */
  Role.associate = function(models) {
    Role.belongsToMany(
      models.User, {
        through: 'user_role',
        foreignKey: 'userId',
      }
    );
  };
  return Role;
};
```

User Model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    uuid: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    ....
  }, {});
  /** @param models.Role */
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.belongsToMany(
      models.Role, {
        through: 'user_role',
        foreignKey: 'roleId',
      }
    );
  };
  return User;
};
```

the migration is the following:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('user', {
      uuid: {
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      },
      ....
    }).then(() => {
      queryInterface.createTable('role', {
        uuid: {
          allowNull: false,
          unique: true,
          primaryKey: true,
          type: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
          defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        },
        ....
      });
    }).then(() => {
      queryInterface.createTable('user_role', {
        userId: {
          type: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
          references: {
            model: 'User',
            key: 'uuid',
          },
          allowNull: false,
        },
        roleId: {
          type: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
          references: {
            model: 'Role',
            key: 'uuid',
          },
          allowNull: false,
        },
        ....
      });
    }).then(() => {
      return queryInterface.addConstraint('user_role', ['UserId', 'RoleId'], {
        unique: true,
        type: 'primary key',
        name: 'userrole_pkey',
      });
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    ....
  },
};
```

if i try to insert now a user with a new role:

```
let models = require('../models');
models.Role.create({
  role: 'Administrator',
  description: 'Administrator Gruppe',
}).then(role => {
  models.User.create({
    login: 'admin',
    password: '123',
    nick: 'Admini',
    mail: 'admin@localhost.com',
  }).then(user => {
    user.addRole(role);
    user.save().then(() => {
      console.log('admin created');
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

it tries to add the role uuid in the userid and the user uuid in the roleid.. and for that the constraint fails...

any hints or tips where i made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the mistake myself (with help of a college)

at

```
  models.User, {
    through: 'user_role',
    foreignKey: 'userId',
  }
```

i set the wrong foreign key, it's not the field in the helper table, it's needed to be the source table (in this case uuid of user model) or leave it blank for sequelize's default behaviour to use the primary key.